# Sending and storing data from BlackBerry to Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blackberry

I don't know if my question belongs here..
I need my BlackBerry to send and store location data in GAE , i'm using BB and GAE plugins for Eclipse, there is no literature about how to develop such an app. I wonder which architecture should I use, and how to do it on Eclipse (should I consider it as a BB project or a web project or both, how to send data to GAE with a BB) ?

Comment: For more information, I speak java/SQL/php/ .. so my problem is not with the programming languages but with the architecture itself and how to implement it on Eclipse..